# Frase com diferentes formatações HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css

Qual a melhor maneira de escrever um código com uma frase que contenha diversas formatações de font.

EX:

Essa frase (negrito e cor azul) que estou escrevendo de exemplo (italico nao negrito e cor vermelha) contem entre parenteses a formatação de cada palavra, entretanto como seria um bom código escrito utilizando html e css. (o resto do texto quero font 50 e cor branca)

Detalhe sei que se eu ficar abrindo tag por tag daria certo, entretanto no html esse texto não ficaria na mesma linha como se fosse parte de um paragrafo só. 
Relacionado a boas práticas como poderia escrever um código para esse exemplo?

posso utilizar a tag span pra isso?

Comment: O que você quis dizer com "*esse texto não ficaria na mesma linha no HTML*"?

Comment: Quando eu abro um <p> ele cria outro paragrafo e vai para a linha de baixo

Comment: Ah, isso sim. Mas se utilizar elementos que possuem o `display: inline` isso não acontecerá, tal como o `span`, que citou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sempre a tag `<p>` nos parágrafos e sempre que for mudar a formatação no meio do parágrafo use a tag `<span>`.
Procure evitar css inline, tipo `<span style="color: #d9d9db; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;">` use classes (procure dar nomes consistentes) css para fazer isso, pois reduz o tamanho das suas páginas html e o css fica no cache do navegado. o código com css inline ficaria `<span class="cinza-negrito">`

Outra dica que sugiro é usar algum framework css como o do [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) para sua formatação inicial.